# fetch rows from SQL db within certain time period: d:m:y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL with a `date` column, listing the date the row was inserted:

```
date
2011-12-19
2011-12-20
2011-12-21
2011-12-22
2011-12-23

ect ect....
```

Now I need to `SELECT` rows which are in a certain time period (example: 2011-12-19 - 2011-12-22).

The time period may be months, to even years..

Anyone know how I could accomplish this with PHP?

Comment: Don't you rather want to accomplish this with mySQL? If you're asking about how to make a mySQL query from PHP, please refer to a basic PHP / database tutorial instead. All you need is explained there.

Comment: Do you want us to write the whole PHP program or just give you the select statement?

Comment: Just the select statement thanks. No need now, stefandoorn got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT `t`.* FROM `table` AS t WHERE `t`.`date` BETWEEN ' . $dateStart . ' AND ' . $dateEnd;
```

Or:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `t`.* FROM `table` AS t WHERE `t`.`date` >= ' . $dateStart . ' AND `t`.`date` <= ' . $dateEnd;
```

Then execute it:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error();
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $fetch['date'];
}
```